# Eigenvalues of linear operator TS and ST for infinite dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here is the original problem:
Let $S$ and $T$ be linear operators on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Show that $TS$ and $ST$ have the same eigenvalues.

I can prove it. However, my question is: Is it also true for infinite dimensional vector space $V$? What is the counter-example for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always true that two linear operators share the same *nonzero* eigenvalues, regardless of the dimension of the vector space. However, in the finite case, it is also true that $TS$ is invertible if and only if $ST$ is, thus also settling the case of the zero eigenvalue.

The standard counterexample for this in infinite dimensions is to let $V = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, the set of all sequences of the form $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum a_n^2 < \infty$. Let $R$ be the right shift, and $L$ the left-shift. Then $LR = I$, but $RL$ is not invertible.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{l} ^2 (\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: @dh87, I have now elaborated further above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does the left shift mean $L(a_n) = a_{n-1}$? Similar to the right shift?

Comment: Right, basically. If $e_n$ is the $n$th coordinate vector, then $L(e_n) = e_{n-1}$ when $n > 0$, but $L(e_0) = 0$ (this is the source of the noninvertibility). And the right shift is $R(e_n) = e_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes a lot of sense.